# Why does Babel add this duplicate line of code to my build?

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I'm using Babel 7 and Gulp 4 together, and found that the following line of code appears 5 times in my build:

```
function _typeof(obj) { "@babel/helpers - typeof"; if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems redundant? Details of my configuration can be found below:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^1.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
}
```

**gulpfile.babel.js** (including only the function used for the build task)

```
function createBuildTask() {
    var sourceArray = [
        // I'm building from 12 different files, but have simplified for this posting
        'file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js', 'file4.js', ...
    ];

    return function () {
        return gulp.src(sourceArray, {'allowEmpty': true})
            .pipe(babel({
                'presets': ['@babel/preset-env'],
                'plugins': []
            }))
            .pipe(concat('desktop-built.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('desktop/dist'))
            .pipe(terser())
            .pipe(rename({
                'extname': '.min.js'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('desktop/dist'));
    };
}
```

**What I've tried**:

1. Passing in options to @babel/preset-env:

   `'presets': [['@babel/preset-env', {
       'modules': false,
       'useBuiltIns': 'entry',
       'corejs': 3
   }]],
   'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']`

...but the **duplicate** lines of code for Symbol are still there once compiled.

What is the correct way to do this, so that the aforementioned line of code appears only once?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the new ES6 `Symbol()` type. If you don’t use it, you can avoid that kind of namespace pollution, but you need to exclude as option to the preset (found by trial and error):

```
--- a/babel.config.json
+++ b/babel.config.json
@@ -1,15 +1,18 @@
 {
   "plugins": [
     "@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode",
     "add-module-exports"
   ],
   "presets": [
     [
       "@babel/env",
       {
         "bugfixes": true,
+        "exclude": [
+          "@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol"
+        ],
         "modules": "auto"
       }
     ]
   ]
 }
```